# Datagrid on VB.net auto complete the other column?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagrid

I have a datagrid and I have imported it to my project under vb.net language, and the database is MS access...
any way in this datagrid one table call
"**Employees**"
**ID - Name - Nationality - Job title**
and what I want is **when I write the ID number of the Employee, all the other details automatically comes upon to his ID number.**

Comment: This is probably going to get closed.  You might want to read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554/159514).

Comment: @Samir Please do some gooogling and come 2 stack if google dont satisfies u

Comment: For three days I'm looking for solution, I didn't find anything ... all of the posts was short or wrong ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found near answer I made it by my self ...
But it shown the result in combobox not text box :'(

```
    Dim dgvc1 As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    Dim index1 As Integer = DataGridView1.Columns.IndexOf(DataGridView1.Columns("code"))
    Dim index11 As Integer = DataGridView1.Columns.IndexOf(DataGridView1.Columns("nu"))
    Dim index111 As Integer = DataGridView1.Columns.IndexOf(DataGridView1.Columns("aaa"))
    Dim dgvc11 As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()



    dgvc1.Name = "Code Meaning"
    dgvc1.DataPropertyName = "nu"
    dgvc1.ValueMember = "nu"
    dgvc1.DisplayMember = "code"
    dgvc1.DataSource = CodesTableAdapter.GetData()


    dgvc1.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic


    If DataGridView1.Columns.Contains(dgvc1) = False Then
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(index1, dgvc1)
    Else
    End If

    dgvc1.ReadOnly = True
    dgvc1.Width = 250




    dgvc11.Name = "meaning total"
    dgvc11.DataPropertyName = "nu"
    dgvc11.ValueMember = "nu"
    dgvc11.DisplayMember = "aaa"
    dgvc11.DataSource = CodesTableAdapter.GetData()


    dgvc11.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic


    If DataGridView1.Columns.Contains(dgvc11) = False Then
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(index111, dgvc11)
    Else
    End If

    dgvc11.ReadOnly = True
    dgvc11.Width = 250
    dgvc11.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
    dgvc11.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
```